# Почему отличаются apk дев и релиз версий ( react-native)?

Tags: android, react-native, apk

Сборка релиз версии  приложения  отличается  от тестовой. Не могу понять причины отличия -  сборка  производится через `./grablew assemblerRelease`
 запуск в дев режиме - `react-native run-undroid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разные конфигурации сборки для gradle.
При обычных конфигах, если кратко, релизный билд подписывается релизными сертификатами и в них не включается JS Dev-Mode, используемый для отладки.

`./gradlew assembleRelease` - команда сборщика gradle, `react-native run-undroid` - комплексная команда, которая сначала собирает JS Bundle, потом вызывает сборщик gradle (`assembleDebug`) и установку сборки на девайс.